# I am storing some data in XML files in a SQL Server as varbinary. How to create concurrent access?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, acid

Whenever a user wants to edit or read some data, he gets a copy of the XML file in his application. At this time, another user must not be allowed to edit the same XML file but should be able to view it. I could add a locked column to the SQL Server table where the XML file is stored but I still cannot allow read and prevent only write for the second user. Or is there any other way to to guarantee concurrency and atomicity of the data in the XML file?

Comment: Could you store *who* (uniquely) has it locked in a`LockedBy` column (or similar)? Then you can determine whether someone else has read-only or write access. You may need a mechanism to let somebody know that their read-only version has been updated when the lock is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a Locking Column(s) on the table. When someone clicks to edit, they request the lock. That's pretty easy to do with EF - Just set the Concurrency value of the 'LockedTime' and/or 'LockedBy' Property to fixed.

I suggest having both a 'LockedBy' and a 'LockedTime'; That way if some user forgets to leave, you can still have someone else eventually go in and edit the data.

In that case, you'll possibly want to store the 'original' XML in the model/view, and perform an update only when the 'original' XML is still what's in the database.